# Importing problem that need to be resolved

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, lstm, molecule

Good evening everyone, i am working on a molecule design project, and i chose mollstm model to predict new molecule from existing ones using smiles( entered as an input )

while taping this: from mol_lstm import MolLSTM, this error occurs:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mol_lstm (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mol_lstm ( i couldn't install the package ) what to do?
[image]

Comment: This library does not exist.